# How to hyperlink a local file location VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to link a local file location to a already set excel cell. The link is saved into a local varible. I am having a issue hyperlinking the file adress.

```
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add(Q:\Personnel\Read\QTF Employees\Active\testname.QTF.ptf)
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveCell,"file:///Q:\Personnel\Read\QTF Employees\Active\testname.QTF.ptf")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
With ActiveCell
  .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(ActiveCell.Address), _
  Address:="file:///Q:\Personnel\Read\QTF Employees\Active\testname.QTF.ptf", _
  TextToDisplay:="Test"
End With
```

Comment: If you don't do `TextToDisplay:="Test"`, it will just display the file link.

Comment: @bulbus I was taught to add that when I was in a VBA class. That's cool to know for the future.

Comment: For some reason it works but its placing it in a weird cell far down from where the active cell is.

Comment: I ended up find another way around it, messy but still works. I am attempting to use Activecell.address in another location and it is not keeping the address even after being saved in a varible.

Comment: To put the link in the active cell, you need to set the range like this : .Range("$A$1") . The range is positioned relative to the active cell. Also, instead of "Test", you can use .Value to keep the original value if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out you need to replace `Anchor:=.Range(ActiveCell.Address)` with `Anchor:=.Range(Range("A1").Address)` in order to prevent the wrong cell will be linked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with incorrectly placed hyperlinks can be solved easier: it seems there's no need to specify `Anchor:=` value. Check this [link](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/hyperlinks/). So, using @DaBeau96 answer your code could simply look like this (tested on Excel 2016):

```
With ActiveCell
  .Hyperlinks.Add Address:="file:///Q:\Personnel\Read\QTF Employees\Active\testname.QTF.ptf", _
  TextToDisplay:="Test"
End With
```

Presumably MSDN and VBA's hints are incorrect because, according to them, `.Hyperlinks.Add` method requires `Anchor:=` argument.